# How to save to XML file

Tags: php, xml

I have 2 files:
This works how I wanted to. But I don't know how to write results back to xml file.
The Xml should contain all the fields thats are in original file but in diferent order sorted by name

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
    <ProgramData>
      <DeviceGroup Name="Wrocław">
        <Device>
          <Comunicator/>
          <Identity>
            <response>
              <identity_device>
                <modules>
                  <module/>
                  <module/>
                  <module/>
                  <module/>
                </modules>
                <primarylog/>
                <secondarylog/>
                <configfiles/>
              </identity_device>
            </response>
          </Identity>
        </Device>
      </DeviceGroup>
      <DeviceGroup Name="Lublin">
        <Device>
          <Comunicator/>
          <Identity>
            <response>
              <identity_device>
                <modules>
                  <module/>
                  <module/>
                  <module/>
                  <module/>
                </modules>
                <primarylog/>
                <secondarylog/>
                <configfiles/>
              </identity_device>
            </response>
          </Identity>
        </Device>
      </DeviceGroup>
    </ProgramData>
```

**PHP file:**

```
    <?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('obiekty.xml');
    $ob = $xml->xpath('/ProgramData/DeviceGroup');
    function sort_ob($t1, $t2) {
        return strcmp($t1['Name'], $t2['Name']);
    }
    usort($ob, 'sort_ob');
    var_dump($ob);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `DomDocument` and import your sorted data into it.

Here is a code to save your sorted data :

```
// Your code
$xml = simplexml_load_file('obiekty.xml');
$ob = $xml->xpath('/ProgramData/DeviceGroup');
function sort_ob($t1, $t2) {
    return strcmp($t1['Name'], $t2['Name']);
}
usort($ob, 'sort_ob');

// Code to save $ob array :
$doc = new DomDocument("1.0", "windows-1250") ;
$rnode = $doc->createElement("ProgramData") ; // recreate the root node
$doc->appendChild($rnode) ;
foreach ($ob as $elm) {
    $node = dom_import_simplexml($elm) ;
    $node = $doc->importNode($node, true) ; // true to keep "deep" data.
    $rnode->appendChild($node) ;
}
$doc->save("out.xml") ; // save the recreated XML into a file.
```

`out.xml` will contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<ProgramData>
  <DeviceGroup Name="Lublin">
    <!-- skipped content but present in file -->
  </DeviceGroup>
  <DeviceGroup Name="Wrocław">
    <!-- skipped content but present in file -->
  </DeviceGroup>
</ProgramData>
```

Comment: That is great thx but i have another question for you. Im using usort but i have problems with Polish letters Like Ł Ć and other. Is there any way to sort it with those letters??? Becouse for example there is Lublin, Wrocław nad Łódź and here is the problem. I will get sorted Lublin and Wrocław but Łódź will be the last

Comment: @MichałNowak You have to find a comparison function that accept encoding. Maybe this could helps you : https://pastebin.com/d9kyBjBr or something like this. Try to make a test in a separate script to isolate the problem or ask a new question on SO.

Comment: If this anwser works for your question, please check it to mark your question as solved. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Thanks a lot.